# Calculating the time for a specific distance between two lines in ℝ3

Tags: vectors, 3d

I have given two lines in $ℝ3$:

$p1(t)=v1 * t + P1$

$p2(t)=v2 * t + P2$

where $v1, v2$ are the velocities/slopes and $P1, P2$ are the offsets from the origin.
I'm trying to write an algorithm that calculates the time $t$ at which the distance between the two points $p1(t)$ and $p2(t)$ is at a specific value.

Given a time $t$, I can calculate the positions $p1(t)$, $p2(t)$ on those two lines.
The distance between $p1(t)$ and $p2(t)$ at any given time should be

$d = \sqrt{(p2(t)_x - p1(t)_x)^2 + (p2(t)_y - p1(t)_y)^2 + (p2(t)_z - p1(t)_z)^2}$

or

$d = \sqrt{(v2_xt + P2_x - v1_xt-P1_x)^2 + (v2_yt + P2_y - v1_yt-P1_y)^2 + (v2_zt + P2_z - v1_zt-P1_z)^2}$

If this is correct, then solving the equation for $t$ should give me the formula for calculating the the time $t$ at a given distance $d$.

However, solving this equation for $t$ turned out harder than I thought. Is there a simpler approach to this problem?

Comment: what do you exactly mean for a simpler approach? it depends upon the kind of data you have and how you need to handle them, is it a numerical issue or you are looking for an analytical solution?

Comment: If there is a relatively easy pure mathematical way I would prefer that over an algorithmic approach. However, ultimately I'm looking for a computationally cheap way to solve this problem. So if someone has an idea on how to solve this in completely different way, I'd be happy if you share your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight rewriting of your problem:

$$
p(t) = tv + d\\
q(t) = tw + e
$$
You want to solve for when $\| p(t) - q(t) \|^2 = K$.

Write $\|u \|^2 = u \cdot u$, and apply this to get
$$
\| t(v-w) + (d-e) \|^2 = K
$$
To make things easier, let's call $u = v-w$ and $b = (d-e)$. Then we want to find $t$ with 
$$
\| tu + b \|^2 = K
$$
i.e.
\begin{align}
K 
&= (tu + b) \cdot (tu + b) \\
&= t(u \cdot u) + 2 t (u \cdot b) +   b \cdot b \\
0 &= t(u \cdot u) + 2 t (u \cdot b) +   (b \cdot b - K).
\end{align}
Now let
$$
A = u \cdot u \\
B = 2 (u \cdot b)\\
C = (b \cdot b - K)
$$
and you've got a quadratic, 
$$
0 = At^2 + Bt + C
$$
whose solution is 
$$
t = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}
$$
I'll let you do the (small) algebraic work to simplify that to something in terms of $u$ and $b$.

Now you also know why folks like to use dot-products rather than writing out individual terms: it helps see the bigger picture.

Notice, too, that the problem of solving this for two lines reduced, after the first couple of steps, to finding when a SINGLE line made its closest approach to the origin; that's a typical thing, and corresponds to the idea in physics that it's often wise to choose a good frame of reference. (In this case, the frame is one that moves along the first line!)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you explain why the term ||p(t) - q(t)|| is squared? I thought ||p(t) - q(t)|| = K (like in the first formula for 'd' in the question).

Comment: If you want the distance to be $Q$, you can set the squared distance to be $Q^2$. So my $K$ is your $d$, squared. Why use **squared** distance? No square roots, so the algebra's nicer.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. What a nice way of solving the equation. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The first one

$$d = \sqrt{(p_2(t)_x - p_1(t)_x)^2 + (p_2(t)_y - p_1(t)_y)^2 + (p_2(t)_z - p_1(t)_z)^2}$$

is correct by Pythagoras theorem and equivalent to the second one.

To simplify we can simply consider $d^2$ to avoid the square root. I can't see other methods to evaluate $d$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But to bring t on one side of the equation, I then need to replace the terms p2(t) - p1(t) with the equations of the lines, or am i mistaken? I tried doing this and ended up with a half-page long formula. Therefore, I was in believe that I was doing something wrong.

Comment: @user3067395 the set up of the problem is correct, could you show some detail more in order to better understand what you are looking for? Thanks